# how to enforce HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) on AWS AppSync GraphQL response?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, graphql, aws-appsync, hsts

I have a very straight forward graphQL app built on top of AWS AppSync, and I want to configure support for HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS)
so that's my question how can I enforce a support HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) on AWS AppSync
or how can I add an HTTP header in the AppSync response

Answer (score 2):

I remember that in the past it wasn't possible to add headers to AppSync responses using response mappings. Maybe this changed or will change in the future. You can test it. If it still doesn't work you can add a cloudfront distribution in front of AppSync API and use Lambda@Edge to add the headers to your request.

You can find more information about how to it in these two amazon articles:

1. [Use a custom domain with AWS AppSync, Amazon CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/use-a-custom-domain-with-aws-appsync-amazon-cloudfront-and-amazon-route-53/)
2. [Adding HTTP Security Headers Using Lambda@Edge and Amazon CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/adding-http-security-headers-using-lambdaedge-and-amazon-cloudfront/)

Comment: Please note that this "Adding HTTP Security Headers Using Lambda@Edge and Amazon CloudFront" guide is from year 2017. Lambda web gui layout and logic changed considerably since then. If you're not familiar with it, you will have quite a lot of head scratching to set up HSTS by following these instructions!